# Is there a police station in Brussels airport?

Tags: airports, brussels

I need to make a complaint, due to a stolen item during the last time I was in Brussels. I would like to know if there is a police station, at the airport, where this can be done.

I will be traveling through Brussels airport, and it would be very convenient.

I can't find anything in the aiport website.

Comment: Aren't there information desks? If you are there seems like the first place to go to ask.

Comment: The [Federal Police offices/station appear to be in the Satellite building](https://www.brusselsairport.be/en/cargo/cargo-contacts/government), not within the arrivals/departure terminal, more easily visualized in [this how-to-get-there document](https://www.brusselsairport.be/uploads/media/default/0001/12/3b2e25add66ea814722ea94d9ca39410cb12dc47.pdf)

Comment: What leads you to think I am there?

Comment: The fact that your original question indicated that "[you] *am* traveling through"? Of course the point is still valid that the information desks will still be there for inquiries regardless of if you're there now or will get there next week.

Comment: I changed to avoid miss understandings. But I mentioned I was going through Brussels, not in Brussels airport.

Answer (score 2):

While there is obviously a [police presence at the airport](https://www.brusselsairport.be/en/passngr/at-the-airport/police), they deal with things like smuggling, human trafficking etc. There is no station of the local police where you would make a complaint about a regular theft at the airport.

The [nearest local police station](http://www.lokalepolitie.be/5400/contact/commissariaten/1-zonecommissariaat) is in the Hoogstraat 20 in Zaventem. If the stolen item was a bicycle or light motorcycle you can simply [make the complaint online](https://policeonweb.belgium.be).